# Can't scrape the same page twice

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyqt, scrape

I'm trying to scrape the website
https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/28083

this is the code I have written so far

```
class Client(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()


Price = []
url = 'https://www.realtor.com/realestateandhomes-search/28083'
client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for link in soup.findAll('span', class_='data-price-display'):
    Price.append(link.text)
```

run it and everything works fine the first time.
After it runs right the first time. I run it again, doesn't scrape any data and just returns '[]' for the value of price

After running it successfully, I copied and pasted the exact code that worked previously into a blank document and ran it again. it returned nothing.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is the data correctly fetched in source? It's working with urllib3 :)

Comment: I ran this: (for link in soup.findAll('span'): print(link))  and it's not returning the data I see when I view the page source

Answer (score 0):

```
 Price.append(link.text)
```

Needs to be indented, since it's under a for-loop but it doesn't look like it is, at least here on SO. Is it the same in your code? Also is this your whole code? I don't see where the class Client is instantiated --

Comment: Yes, it is indented in my code. I'll edit the post to fix it. I call the client here "client_response = Client(url)"